# subscription in app.component file works only once (not working twice)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a parent class in which, i have a method. In this method i have a subscription.

code look like this:

```
 parentMethod(){
     this.token.subscribed(token=>{
     this.profile.next(token);
   });
 }
```

when it fire `this.profile.next()`, it wont go in subscription of profile which is in **app.component.ts** (child class). It though goes there once, when app loads.

code loo like this in **app.component.ts**:

```
 freshToken(){  //being called from constructor of app.component.ts
    this.profile.subscribe(
    (val)=>{
    console.log("Firing once");
   });
  }
```

and i am using **subjects**.

can any one tell me, why it is not firing every time?
and how to make it fire every-time?

Comment: Please edit your question with what those functions do

Comment: Ok, gimme a sec

Comment: @ahsanayub: what is the code in the observable of `this.token` ?  is it `http` call ?

Comment: @ahsanayub : `this.profile` will only emit value when `this.token` emits value

Comment: @ShashankVivek its an replySubject , that checks token from storage.

Comment: @ShashankVivek but i have console.log() above this.profile.next();, and it is priniting message. so it is going into this method.

Comment: @ShashankVivek i am on Home.page.ts because app.component loads route /home.

Comment: And if i check on **home.page.ts** , it works fine

Comment: @ahsanayub: Its impossible to answer this unless you can provide some more details. Can you replicate this issue on stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a servise for do this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {

    private yourVariable: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


    public listenYourVariable() {
        return this.yourVariable.asObservable();

    }


    public yourVariableObserver(value ?: type) {
        this.yourVariable.next(value);
    }
```

You import in yours components where you want use it this service.

```
import{ YourService } from ...
```

In other component :

```
submit(){
    this.yourService.yourVariableObserver();
}
```

while in app component

```
gOnInit() {
   this.sub=this.yourService.listenYourVariable().subscribe(
            variable => {
              this.callyourFunction();
            }

        )
    }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a publish method, which emits an event, and a receive method, which is responsible for listening for event. I that you have created and observable which you publish events to.
In you case the this.profile.next(token) could be your emit method. The receive method should be inside a ngOnInit hook or a constructor.

Here is some sample code on how this could be implemented.
I created a data.service.ts file, which contains the methods for emitting and receiving events

**data.service.ts**

```
export class DataService {
private profileSubject = new Subject<any>()

 constructor() {}

   getProfileSubject() {
    return this.profileSubject;

  }
  publishProfileSubject(data) {
    this.profileSubject.next(data);

  }

}
```

You can call this method when you need to emit a event.

```
publishProfileSubject(data) {
  this.profileSubject.next(data);

  }
```

And you can call this method when you want to listen for new events. As mention before, you should ideally initialise the function inside a hook ex. ngOnInit and subscribe to the function.

Comment: Your and **FedMice** approach is nearly same, i implemented his approach first and it worked, and accepted that one as answer.
I up voted your answer too. :)